# How to calculate the 3D coordinate from a picture with given Z-value

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2010

I've got a picture of a plane with 4 known points on it. I've got the intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters and also (using the Rodriguez function) the position of the camera. The plane is defined as my ground level (Z = 0). If I select a point in my image, is there an easy way to calculate the coordinates, where this point would be on my plane?

Comment: Maybe try using the docs of opencv. I have never worked with the library, but hopefully this helps [opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/df8/tutorial_root.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not much can be labeled as 'easy' when dealing with 3D rendering.

For your question, I would look into [ray tracing](https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/raytrace/rtinter0.htm). I am not going to try to explain it, as most sites will do a better job of explaining it then I can.

Comment: But how do I get the line that connects my camera position and the virtual point on my image surface? If I got that, it's easy to calculate the intersection with my plane

Answer (score 0):

When you look at opencv in calib3d module. you will see this equation:

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html

Please scroll down the link and see the perspective transformation equations

From what you say, you declare the plane ground level(Z=0). you also know the internsic (focal point in pixels , image center) camera parameter and you know the exterinsic (rotation and translation) camera parameter. and you want to access some pixels in your image (is it?) and from there, you want to estimate where it is on the plane??

You can use triangulatePoints() function in calib3D module of opencv. you need at least 2 images tough.

But your case seems unlikely to me, if you try to detect 4 known points, you will have to define the world coordinate of those plane first, usually, you define top left corner of the plane as original (0,0,0), then, you will know the position of those 4 known points in world coordinate by manual calculation. when you detect it in opencv program, it gives you the pixel coordinates of those 4 points. then, usually, what people expect to calculate is the pose ( rotation and translation ).

Alternatively, if your case is what you said, you can make a simple matrix operation code based on perspective transformation equation.

Comment: I used the 4 known points and their corresponding coordinates on my image to calculate the extrinsic parameters and the camera position (solvePnp --> rodriguez matrix). I should not need 2 different camera perspectives since I know one coordinate (Z = 0)...